# Outputting multiple jpegs dynamically created, into webpage

Tags: php, loops, header, jpeg, gd

So I have this code which can create a jpeg rectangle.

```
<?php
// Create a 200 x 200 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 500);

// Allocate colors
//$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
//$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

// Draw three rectangles each with its own color
//imagerectangle($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 150, $pink);
//imagerectangle($canvas, 100, 120, 75, 160, $green);
imagerectangle($canvas, 0, 0, 120, 100, $white);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```

Is there any way, I can run this in a loop to get multiple rectangles outputted into the webpage.

PLEASE NOTE: I do not want multiple rectangles in the same canvas. I want a canvas with a rectangle in it. The next canvas with another rectangle in it, etc. I tried running this in a loop, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this purely with PHP. You can only output a single image, and you explicitly state 'I do not want multiple rectangles in the same canvas'.

You would need to create multiple references in your HTML, probably passing parameters to be used by PHP in creating the image:

```
<img src="/path/to/php?width=100&height=200">
<img src="/path/to/php?width=200&height=100">
<img src="/path/to/php?width=500&height=500">
...
```

And in the PHP (*this is just an example; **validate all parameters!***):

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($_GET['width'], $_GET['height']);
...
```